# jquery post to codeigniter problem

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Ok, this is really driving me nuts.

I want to post a variable from jQuery to CodeIgniter. This is the code jQuery code I'm using:

jQuery call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
    url:  'http://sandbox.dev/tmp/livesearch',
    data: {
        "query": 'q_val',
        output: 'json',
        page: CURRENT_PAGE,
        limit: CURRENT_LIMIT
    },
    timeout:    '5000',
    dataType:   'json',
    beforeSend: function() {

    },
    complete: function() {

    },
    success: function(data, textStatus) {

    },

    // We're gonna hide everything when get error
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
});
```

I've stripped to code to make it easier to read. The problem is that I end up in the error function with error code 200... which from what I've found on internet does not mean that something went wrong. Why isn't success called then? Do anyone have any good tutorial?

Comment: going to need to see the codeigniter controller recieving, and exactly what, in your data, is suppose to be a string litteral and what is suppose to be a variable.

Comment: Do you have firebug installed? What is the response from that page in firebug when you issue the request?

Comment: Yes, I have firebug installed. It shows that I get the error callback with error code 200. jondavidjohn, I'm new with javascript. The string-thing you're talking about is something I've seen in code examples using post. I guess that this is simply a hash key. Will add the controller code from CodeIgniter when I come home.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete').click(function(){
        $.post("http://sandbox.dev/tmp/livesearch", {'query' : "q_val", 'output' : "json", 'page' : CURRENT_PAGE, 'limit' : CURRENT_LIMIT}, function(data) {
             alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```